# AppleScript URL from open safari window

Tags: safari, applescript

I have a Safari window displaying a webpage. I want to be able to retrieve the open URL into AppleScript. However when I do this:

```
if URL of window 1 is "www.google.com" then
    --do something
end if
```

It returns an error of nothing being returned. And I'm pretty sure window 1 exists because in another part of the program I created the window.

**Can someone tell me the mistake I made?**

Comment: This question shows absolutely no research and IMO does not deserve an up-vote since a Google search for [applescript get url safari](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=applescript+get+url+safari&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) would have provided an answer!

Comment: @user3439894 I got confused with the search. I'm very new to AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URL** is a property of a document or a property of a tab in a window, so use this:

```
if URL of document 1 is "www.google.com" then
```

or this:

```
if URL of current tab of window 1 is "www.google.com" then
```

---

**Update**, example of how to use the `exists` command:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set b to exists URL of document 1 -- this put false or true into the variable
    if b and URL of document 1 is "www.google.com" then
        -- do something
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I was literally getting ready to post an answer when the message came up that an answer has been posted. Since your's was better written then mine I decided not to post it and instead just +1 yours! :)

Comment: error "No result was returned from some part of this expression." number -2763

Comment: You get this error because it's a blank page or the page is not loaded, so use a `try` block, or the `exists` command

Comment: I solved it a different way. Yea it was because the page wasn't fully loaded. And I had to set a string property to the URL before comparing in the If loop. I used try and end try.